# Add column if it does not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssms

I am running SSIS for data warehousing purposes basically it loops through all my databases and saves that data into a table. However, some tables are missing a `[LastModified]` column and I would like to create the column for those that do not match.

This is my select statement -

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE Name = N'LastModified'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Branch'))
(SELECT [ID]
,ISNULL([Name], '') AS [Name]
,ISNULL([Code], '') AS [Code]
,ISNULL([LastModified], '') AS [LastModified]
,[TimeStampField] from [dbo].[Branch])
ELSE
(SELECT [ID]
,ISNULL([Name], '') AS [Name]
,ISNULL([Code], '') AS [Code]
,getdate() AS [LastModified]
,[TimeStampField] from [dbo].[Branch])
```

I get the error - Invalid column name 'LastModified'.

If I change `ISNULL([LastModified], '') AS [LastModified]` to `GetDate() AS [LastModified]` it works. However, this will change the date on those tables which have the `[LastModified]` column.

Is there a better way to implement this, the Derived Column function maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE Name = N'LastModified'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Branch'))
SET @sql = 'SELECT [ID]
,ISNULL([Name], '') AS [Name]
,ISNULL([Code], '') AS [Code]
,ISNULL([LastModified], '') AS [LastModified]
,[TimeStampField] from [dbo].[Branch]';
ELSE
SET @sql = 'SELECT [ID]
,ISNULL([Name], '') AS [Name]
,ISNULL([Code], '') AS [Code]
,getdate() AS [LastModified]
,[TimeStampField] from [dbo].[Branch]';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Using Dynamic SQL hides from the parser the fact that one of the possible paths in your code references a column that doesn't exist.